# NSubstitute -3.x 'ValueType' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'netstandard,

Tags: c#, .net, nsubstitute

I am struggling to find a reason behind this error in my code:

> ApplicationServiceTests\Test.cs(29, 13): error CS0012: The
>   type 'ValueType' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You
>   must add a reference to assembly 'netstandard, Version=2.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51'.

The code line is:

```
        repo.GetCoveredCards(Arg.Is(cifCode)).Returns(Task.FromResult(new GetCustomerCCPlusResponse()
        {
            CreditCardPlus = new[] { card1, card2 }
        }));
```

Tools, framework and Package

.net framework 4.6.1
Visual Studio 2015 using MSBuild 14.
NSubstitute 3.1.0

It seems like when I use NSubstitute version 1.10.0 and it has worked really well.

Now the question is why am I getting this error with the latest version of NSubstitute?

Comment: seems like you chose the .net standard version of their library - perhaps there is a version more compatible for you?

Comment: No, the target framework, where I am installing this package is 4.6.1. Hence it should not haev referred standard at all. I could not see any dependency added by the system.

Comment: can you post the csproj xml?

Comment: check out the dependencies here - 

https://www.nuget.org/packages/NSubstitute/3.1.0

You are certainly missing out something in the dependencies, thus leading to an error

Comment: `NSubstitute version 1.10.0` did not have any dependency

Comment: NSubstitute used to ship all its dependencies in the download. Now it relies on NuGet. I wonder if the version of NuGet on your machine is not doing this correctly? I found [a workaround](https://github.com/dotnet/standard/issues/542#issuecomment-339516364) for a similar sounding problem, but not sure it will help in this case.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue after updating Visual studio.
Delete the bin and obj folders from the UT project folder and rebuild the project. That fixed it for me.